# Merge Datatable records using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a DataTable as like below,

```
Company      Manager       Location      Count1      Count2      Count3
------------ ------------- ------------- ----------- ---------- --------
C1           Mgr           LocName       1           0            0  
C1           Mgr           LocName       0           3            0
C1           Mgr           LocName       0           0            7
C2           Mgr2          LocName2      0           0            5
```

But, I want to display this table as,

```
Company      Manager       Location      Count1      Count2      Count3
------------ ------------- ------------- ----------- ---------- --------
C1           Mgr           LocName       1           3            7  
C2           Mgr2          LocName2      0           0            5
```

Can any one help me...
Thanks in adv.

Comment: Linq-To-Sql tag, why? Also, what means _display_? You want to modify the original table?

Comment: if i use Linq-To-Sql, then the perforation will goes good. Am I right?  Because I have lot of records in my DataTable.

Comment: Shouldnt your expected result have a `2` in Count1 for the first row?

Comment: If you have a LOT of records as you say, wouldn't it be quicker to do this kind of aggregation in SQL? Indeed this is what it's good at...

Comment: Sorry, I written wrongly in 2nd row. That should be zero at Count1.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you please check once.

Comment: So now its confusing - do you want a `sum` of the values in `count[1-3]` or the single item with a value `>0`?

Comment: Single item with value >0.

Comment: @Jamiec: the result is the same if there's only one value > 0. If not, OP needs to clarify his requirement (and improve the sample data) anyway.

Comment: And what if more than 1 row contains a count > 0? Do you want the first? The last?

Comment: That's great, but doesn't answer the question. What if 2 or more rows to be grouped all have a value for one of the columns?

Comment: Yes, In that case I need to show the sum of count only. But Jamice I will not get that type of case to my Data table.

Comment: Because, that count is comes according to Date.

Comment: @Chinni: however, i've shown both ways in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21044069/284240), do you have problems to implement it? Instead of the `FirstOrDefault` or `Sum` apporaches you could also implement a different logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.GroupBy` + `Sum`:

```
var companyGroups = tblCompany.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => new {
        Company = row.Field<string>("Company"),
        Manager = row.Field<string>("Manager"),
        Location = row.Field<string>("Location"),
    });
// creates an empty DataTable with the same columns:
var merge = tblCompany.Clone();  
foreach(var companyGroup in  companyGroups)
{
    merge.Rows.Add(
        companyGroup.Key.Company,
        companyGroup.Key.Manager,
        companyGroup.Key.Location,
        companyGroup.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Count1")),
        companyGroup.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Count2")),
        companyGroup.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Count3")));
}
```

Your sample data yields the desired result:

```
var tblCompany = new DataTable();
tblCompany.Columns.Add("Company", typeof(string));
tblCompany.Columns.Add("Manager", typeof(string));
tblCompany.Columns.Add("Location", typeof(string));
tblCompany.Columns.Add("Count1", typeof(int));
tblCompany.Columns.Add("Count2", typeof(int));
tblCompany.Columns.Add("Count3", typeof(int));

tblCompany.Rows.Add("C1", "Mgr", "LocName", 1, 0, 0);
tblCompany.Rows.Add("C1", "Mgr", "LocName", 1, 3, 0);
tblCompany.Rows.Add("C1", "Mgr", "LocName", 0, 0, 7);
tblCompany.Rows.Add("C2", "Mgr2", "LocName2", 0, 0, 5);
```

If you instead want to take the first value `!= 0` of each group:

```
foreach (var companyGroup in companyGroups)
{
    merge.Rows.Add(
        companyGroup.Key.Company,
        companyGroup.Key.Manager,
        companyGroup.Key.Location,
        companyGroup
            .Select(row => row.Field<int>("Count1"))
            .Where(i => i != 0)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        companyGroup
            .Select(row => row.Field<int>("Count2"))
            .Where(i => i != 0)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        companyGroup
            .Select(row => row.Field<int>("Count3"))
            .Where(i => i != 0)
            .FirstOrDefault());
}
```

For the sake of completeness, if you need to modify the original table instead of creating a new one:

```
foreach (var companyGroup in companyGroups)
{
    // modify just the first row of each group, 
    // all others will be removed after the merge
    DataRow first = companyGroup.First();
    first.SetField("Count1", companyGroup.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Count1")));
    first.SetField("Count2", companyGroup.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Count2")));
    first.SetField("Count3", companyGroup.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Count3")));
    foreach (DataRow other in companyGroup.Skip(1))
        tblCompany.Rows.Remove(other);
}
```

Comment: Why the foreach at the end and not just a projection? And whats with the result being totally different to the OP's expected result?

Comment: @Jamiec: because the input is not a `IEnumerable<DataRow>` but groups of an anonymous type and `CopyToDataTable` supports only `DataRow`s.

Comment: @Jamiec: according to the incorrect result, i have removed it from my answer. It was because my sample data had copy/paste typos. Actually it yields the correct result as checked now.

Answer (score 2):

Group rows by three columns (Company, Manager, Location) and calculate sum for Count fields:

```
var query = from r in table.AsEnumerable()
            group r by new { 
               Company = r.Field<string>("Company"),
               Manager = r.Field<string>("Manager"),
               Location = r.Field<string>("Location")
            } into g
            select new {
               g.Key.Company,
               g.Key.Manager,
               g.Key.Location,
               Count1 = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Count1"),
               Count2 = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Count2"),
               Count3 = g.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Count3")
            };
```

And use custom [`CopyToDataTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) method for custom types to create new `DataTable` (if you need it to be `DataTable`) from this query:

```
DataTable result = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

---

If it is possible to do grouping on server side with Linq to Sql, then query will look like:

```
var query = from x in db.TableName
            group r by new { 
               x.Company,
               x.Manager,
               x.Location
            } into g
            select new {
               g.Key.Company,
               g.Key.Manager,
               g.Key.Location,
               Count1 = g.Sum(x => x.Count1),
               Count2 = g.Sum(x => x.Count2),
               Count3 = g.Sum(x => x.Count3)
            };
```

In that case you will avoid downloading all data and calculations on client.